# How to pass complex java object (nested maps and lists) from one apache nifi processor to other?

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I have two functionalities to be implemented through custom nifi processor. The output of the first is input to second. However this output takes form of complex java object (nested hash maps and lists). If I am to implement these two functionalities as separate processors, then how can I pass these complex java objects between two processors. Do I have to convert them to some intermediate form say json or xml and then pass from one processor to another (and then in second processor again convert json/xml back to nested maps and lists)? Or is there some other standard / obvious approach which I miss completely?

**PS:** Currently I ended up putting both functionalities in the same processor so that I don't have to pass output of the first functionality to the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to serialize the data (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html) and pass it through a FlowFile.

Comment: Yeah object serialization / deserializable is what comes to mind when thinking about this scenario, but is that what people out there do in such context (passing object between nifi processors)? I have to explore how can I write serialized data to flow file and deserialize it back again. Also will flow file be able to deal with serialized java objects? Anyone have any experience in this? (I believe, this should be recurring scenario.)

Comment: Flow file content is a byte[] that you can get an InputStream or OutputStream, so the content can be anything you want

Comment: @Mahesha999 I'm not super familiar with NiFi but from what I understand (as Bryan said), FlowFiles contain byte[] data and can easily handle Streams. Serialization makes it very easy to convert struct-like classes to byte[], so I don't think this is a super difficult problem. Converting a byte[] back to a serialized class is also trivial. I recommend you read through the serial docs/tutorial that I linked above, it will really help illuminate your problem.

Comment: When you say "is that what people out there do," I think most processors try to adhere to the principles of Flow-Based Programming, so the interface between these "black box" processors should be independent and the successor should not be tightly coupled to the predecessor. I think a cleaner solution would be to serialize the output to a text representation with a defined schema (JSON or XML) and ingest it in the follow-on processor, as this allows many other processors to interact with the data. If the structure is so complex and this is the only use case, serialized Java is fine.

Comment: @Andy I try to avoid converting to text representations most of the time, but I see the value in a more agnostic approach like you described. I think an even better approach might be to use Google's [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/), which kinda offer the best of both worlds.

Comment: (possibly off topic)2nd processor is going to ultimately convert input to java.io.File. I was thinking whether to serialize File itself or nested map-lists from which File is created. But then I thought whether I can have both? sort of overloading: having same processor behave in slightly different manner based on parameters. Dont know whether overloading concept fit well in nifi context. What if we need to have different flavors of same processor, should we have two different processors or make same processor stuff different objects based on some input arguments? Or am I sounding stupid?

Comment: There's no reason the file can't be the serialized form. The file can be plain bytes. Also, if my answer helped you, I'd appreciate it if you'd accept it :)